# StackTrace.GetFrames() only returns the last frame

Tags: c#, .net, exception, mono

I have this code

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MiddleMethod();
    }


    public static void MiddleMethod() {
        try
        {
            int b = 0;
            int a = 10 / b;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetAllFootprints(e));
        }
    }


    public static string GetAllFootprints(Exception x)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace(x, false);
        var frames = st.GetFrames();
        var traceString = "";
        foreach (var frame in frames)
        {

            traceString += frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName + "@" + frame.GetMethod().Name;
            traceString += "\n";

        }

        return traceString;
    }
}
```

When i run this code i only get the last method where exception happens. like this

```
TestException2.MainClass@MiddleMethod
```

But i want to have caller methods as well in this example Main method. I want a way to print out all the caller methods from beginning to where exception happens. How can i fix this?

Comment: You might be better off doing `var st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1, true);` to get the trace instead.

Comment: @DavidG thank you! Put it in a answer and will accept that as the right answer